# Autoresize titleView in a NavigationBar with autolayout

Tags: cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, constraints, autolayout, titleview

I want a custom UIView in my UINavigationBar between a left and a right BarButtonItem but as wide as possible. For this reason I added a UIView in IB to the NavigationBar. With autolayout disabled everything works as expected with the autoresizing masks. 
But in my storyboard with autolayout enabled I just cann't get it to work. It doesn't look like I can set any constraints in IB for the titleView. If I rotate my device to landscape mode, the UIView has still the same width.
What do I have to do so that the titleView fills the space between my UIBarButtonItems with autolayout enabled?

Thank you for any help

Linard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the issue as following in my code:

```
 - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(__unused UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
 {
 [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

    CGSize navigationBarSize = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size;
    UIView *titleView = self.navigationItem.titleView;
    CGRect titleViewFrame = titleView.frame;
    titleViewFrame.size = navigationBarSize;
    self.navigationItem.titleView.frame = titleViewFrame;
 }
```

I haven't found another solution (with automatic resizing), but I'm open for new and/or better solutions

Linard

Answer (score -4):

You can add constraints in code.

In `viewDidLoad`, you can do something like this:

```
UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
UIView *titleViewSuperview = titleView.superview;
titleView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[titleViewSuperview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:titleView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:titleViewSuperview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1 constant:0]]; // leading
[titleViewSuperview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:titleView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:titleViewSuperview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0]]; // top
[titleViewSuperview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:titleViewSuperview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:titleView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1 constant:0]]; // width
[titleViewSuperview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:titleViewSuperview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:titleView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1 constant:0]]; // height
```

Comment: I get a crash on the width constraint because titleSuperView is null. Has anybody else had any luck?

Comment: In iOS 7 at least, you cannot do modify constraints for UINavigationBar managed by a controller

Comment: @Andy so how can you provide the custom view with (x,y) information ?